# Xamarin forms access element outside a ControlTemplate

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, data-binding, controltemplate

I'm trying to find out a way to access a named element outside a `ControlTemplate`, or viceversa, access a named element inside a `ControlTemplate` from outside, from XAML (not code behind).

Let's suppose I have the following code:

```
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="MyControlTemplate">
            <views:MyView x:Name="MyViewName">
                <views:MyView.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger TargetType="views:MyView" Binding="{Binding MyProperty}" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="MyCollectionView" Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </views:MyView.Triggers>
            </views:MyView>
        </ControlTemplate>

        <ControlTemplate x:Key="MyOtherControlTemplate">
            <views:MyOtherView x:Name="MyViewName"></views:MyView>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ResourceDictionary>

        <CollectionView x:Name="MyCollectionView">
            ...
        </CollectionView>

        <TemplatedView
            Grid.Row="1"
            ControlTemplate="{StaticResource MyControlTemplate}"/>
        <TemplatedView
            Grid.Row="1"
            ControlTemplate="{StaticResource MyOtherControlTemplate}"/>
```

This code is inside a `ContentView`. Which shows, depending on the selected item in the CollectionView, a view (MyView) or another view (MyOtherView). If MyProperty (which is a property inside the view MyView) is True, then I want the collectionView to be disabled. Since MyView is declared inside the ControlTemplate, I can't manage it to access to MyCollectionView

[image]

Where `MyProperty` is a boolean inside `MyView` ViewModel.

This code throws `ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: targetObject`.

Apparently, `MyCollectionView` is unknown inside the `ControlTemplate`

I have also tried to reference to `MyView`'s name in a `DataTrigger` of `MyCollectionView` and it has no result.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: No.. thid doesn't help me at all. I basically want that whenever "MyProperty" is set to true, change my collectionView's background. Since "MyProperty" is declared inside a ControlTemplate, and it has a different viewModel, I don't know how to access to it, to check the value.

Comment: Where MyControlTemplate is being used ? is custom MyView  used somewhere outside of controltemplate? could you please provide a conherent/complete example (complete the code you already posted)? which portion of code causing the exception?

Comment: Check my last edit, maybe it's clearer. The problem is taht I cannot Target from the controlTemplate child element to any element outside the controlTemplate

Comment: Have you think about using [DataTemplateSelector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/selector)?

Comment: I'll take a look. But, I was looking for an easy solution. Maybe there's not. I know that if I declare "MyView" outside the controlTemplate, I can Reference to it and binding to its MyProperty works. The problem comes when its inside the ControlTemplate

Comment: (just a personal opinion, I might be wrong) I think you should reconsider/rethink your design